# How to get MainActivity Arraylist from non Activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two class : one is MainActivity and it has string ArrayList, the other one is not an activity.
I would like to get my string array from the non activity class, how can i do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You create  getter for your arrayList in your non activity class. 
In your activity class, you create a new instance of your non activity class, and then call the getter !

```
MyNonActivityClass myClass = new MyNonActivityClass();
array = myClass.getTheArrayList();
```